# ActiveAdmin filter date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Using Rails 6 and ActiveAdmin 2.6, how would I change the time formatting of a date field? More specifically, I have

```
filter :birthday
```

for my resource. This results in two datepicker input fields, allowing me to filter for records with a birthday between these two dates.
What I want is to format these input values in dd.mm.yyyy, instead of the default yyyy-mm-dd. How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried this https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2285 ?

Comment: Thank you @user63764 for the link that provides the background to the issue. This is essentially how I solved the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to add the following to active_admin.js:

```
$(function() {
  $('.datepicker').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'dd.mm.yy');
  });
});
```

Found from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/activeadmin/5SqgtX1KQnc

See background info here:https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2285